# How do I get syntax highligting in ipywidgets.Textarea?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

Is there an easyish way to get ipywidgets.Textarea to do syntax highlighting?

Comment: You can't. Try ipymonaco instead, however I only can get it to work for notebook=6 and ipywidgets=7.